# Header doesn't scale for mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, menu, responsive

I have a button (log in) in my header on the right, but this one doesn't scale for mobile. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Give us more info about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your issue is caused by the colour of your login logo changing from white on the desktop view, to black on the mobile view. So on mobile, the logo is present but you can't see it.

One suggestion on how you might fix this is to add the following to your CSS

```
.menu_right_mobile .fa.fa-user {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Omg that was definitely it. Now I feel even more nooby. Thanks so much!

Comment: haha ... it happens to everyone. I'm pleased you got unstuck.